# a lot of callback functions

Tags: jquery, callback

I have different effects. I want each one to be executed only when the previous one has finished. The callback function works well when I have 2 or 3 effects. The problem comes when I have a lot of them and each one is quite complex, the code is really difficult to read and follow. Is there any better way to do that? perhaps a more clean and simple way to present the code?

Here is the example to play: http://jsfiddle.net/83xrg/

JQUERY:

```
$("#blue").click(function() {
    $("#blue").fadeOut(4000, function() {
       $("#red").fadeIn(4000);  
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="red"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#blue{
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px; left: 150px;
    width:200px; height:200px;
    background-color:blue;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#red{
    position: absolute;
    top:150px; left:150px;
    width:200px; height: 200px;
    background-color:red;
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: consider learning about `.promise()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refactor to use functions declared outside:

```
function fadeInRed(){
    $("#red").fadeIn(4000); 
}

function fadeOutBlue(){
    $("#blue").fadeOut(4000, fadeInRed);
}

$("#blue").click(fadeOutBlue);
```

Comment: it is clear, simple and works well. It really helps to keep the code more organized

Comment: to call a function it usually is fadeInRed(). Why in this case is fadeInRed without the () ?

Comment: it's because fadeInRed is a parameter of the click() function here it's not actually being called right away. It will be called when the click event is triggered. It's called a callback actually jQuery uses this a lot, check the docs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Promises (an alternative approach to asynchronous callbacks), which [jQuery implements](http://api.jquery.com/promise/).

Example:

```
var blue = $('#blue');

blue.fadeOut(4000);
blue.promise().done(function(){
    $("#red").fadeIn(4000);            
});
```

Comment: It works very well but I am not sure if I understand. How would it be with a third effect?

Comment: @Nrc: `blue.promise().then(function(){ return $("#red").fadeIn(4000).promise(); }).done(function() { /* third effect */ });`. Promise are a powerful concept and they come natively to JS in ES6, so it's really worth to learn and understand them. See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/ and https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/.

Comment: Ok thank you. It is useful but still quite complicated code of one promise inside the other. I do not see any advantage respect one function inside the other?

Answer (score 1):

I always use promise http://api.jquery.com/promise/.
Using this feature you will be able to properly handle all call flows, whether they are to be successful or not be successful.

```
$("#blue").click(function() {
    $("#blue").fadeOut('slow');
    $("#blue").promise().done(function(){
       $("#red").fadeIn(4000);
        $("#red").promise().done(function(){
       $("#green").fadeIn(4000); 
    });
    }); 

});
```

Hope it helps you http://jsfiddle.net/7wv6H/1/

html

```
 <div id="blue"></div>
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
```

css

```
 #blue{
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px; left: 150px;
    width:200px; height:200px;
    background-color:blue;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#red{
    position: absolute;
    top:150px; left:150px;
    width:200px; height: 200px;
    background-color:red;
    display:none;
}
#green{
    position: absolute;
    top:150px; left:150px;
    width:200px; height: 200px;
    background-color:green;
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: thank you. Can you explain it a bit. How would it be with a third effect?

Comment: Is the number of effects  fixed or variable from time to time?